# Accessing MySQL Directly from Android

Tags: android, mysql

I am currently developing an Android application. I want to be able to access MySQL from my website directory without needing to use JSON, SOAP or PHP in order to access MySQL. Is it possible to to import a MySQL connector into an android app.

Thanks for the help

Comment: This has been asked SO many times here. Do a simple search. Bottom line - You will need RESTful or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [protoBufs](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) instead by Google or use mySQL's connector [example here](http://appinventor.blogspot.com/2011/07/android-mysql.html) but using the connector wouldn't be safe as @Shaun said in his answer.  So it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I like how someone actually said its not possible. This is java we are working with isnt it? Its not easy is the answer. You can always take a java library already written for this in full out java, and rewrite it to work with android. The problem? Its not easy, thats why there is not a very well known library for it yet. Theres alot of connection issues, and security issues to think about when doing this from a phone. One, you dont have a dedicated stream of connection (meaning, your connectivity could drop at any moment) and your data could be corrupt, or, you query coudl have left out the LIMIT at the end you could whipe your database. Secondly, you have to worry about the security of your database. Phones are in no way the most secure devices out there, let alone android.

Answer (score 0):

No this isn't possible. You'll require a web service front end.

Comment: not the downvoter, but the reason could be the size of the answer.Could you please elaborate and write the answer why it is not possible and how you can do with web service.Because one line answers will attarct community and moderators to delete it